# XSLT replace text in a node with a string

Tags: replace, nodes

I want to replace part of the node's string value with another value i.e. replace "COOPERMAN PLC" with "CM PLC". My code is in a foreach just to compound matters.

```
<tr>
    <td>Auditors:</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="./financial">
        <td>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./miscellaneous/auditors"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">,
so I fixed with CHOOSE and not REPLACE (Only available in Version 2.0):

```
<tr>
  <td>Auditors:</td>
  <xsl:for-each select="./financial">
    <td>
      <xsl:variable name="auditor" select="./miscellaneous/auditors" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$auditor = 'PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS LLP'">
          <xsl:value-of select="'PWC LLP'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="./miscellaneous/auditors"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```